# Is there any way to determine VIF of some variable that is included in the dataset that has so many variables?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, multicollinearity, r-squared, variance-inflation-factor

I am new in statistics and need some help to determine the VIF value on all my variables/features in the dataset with a lot of variables. I have 98 variables with 76 observations and need to find VIF to do a variable/feature selection

I already know the formula for VIF is:

$VIF = 1/(1-R^2))$

..and $R^2$ is the coefficient of determination that always increases as long the terms are increased. Thus it leads me to an $R^2$ equal to 1 and consequently can't detect the p-value (it is NaN).
[image]

The first to the last column belong to feature, estimated coefficient, SE, tStat,  and pValue. I computed it with MATLAB. The p-value can be determined and $R^2$ is decreased if I was decreasing the variable on model fitting.

Is there any way to determine VIF of some variable that is included in the dataset that has many variables?

Comment: The R2 is obtained by regressing each feature on the rest of the features. So it shouldn't be always increasing. Which function in R are you using to calculate VIF?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the formula below, each time when you calculate VIF for a feature, you are regressing it on the rest of the features. Note that this is applied to continuous variables. In case you would have categorical features, it needs to be generalized VIF. Both are available in [R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-11/topics/vif).

[image]

Comment: Generalized VIF applies to categorical features or to categorical outcomes in a generalized linear model (e.g., logistic regression)? I thought it was the former.

Answer (score 0):

The $R^2$ in the variance inflation factor does not consider the outcome ($Y$) variable; that $R^2$ refers to the $R^2$ of a linear regression that uses all but one feature to predict the feature for which you want to calculate the VIF.

Consequently, run such a regression, and calculate the $R^2$. Then $\dfrac{1}{1-R^2}$ is the VIF of that feature in the original regression. Note that this $R^2$ can and probably will change from feature to feature.

I give an example below.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x1 <- rnorm(N)
x2 <- rnorm(N)
x3 <- x1 + rnorm(N, 0, 0.1)     # Make x3 super correlated with x1
cor(x1, x3)                     # I get 0.9950633
y <- x1 - x2 + x3 + rnorm(N, 0, 2)
L <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)       # Use x1, x2, x3 to predict y
summary(L) 
L1 <- lm(x1 ~ x2 + x3)          # Use x2, x3 to predict x1
1/(1 - summary(L1)$r.squared)   # I get VIF_1 = 101.6301
L2 <- lm(x2 ~ x1 + x3)          # Use x1, x3 to predict x2
1/(1 - summary(L2)$r.squared)   # I get VIF_2 = 1.00097
L3 <- lm(x3 ~ x1 + x2)          # Use x1, x2 to predict x3
1/(1 - summary(L3)$r.squared)   # I get VIF_3 = 101.6308
```

That `x1` and `x3` are highly correlated and have that huge VIF value explains why, despite the effet sizes all being about the same, the coefficients on `x1` and `x2` have much larger p-values than the coefficient on `x2`, due to the much larger standard error caused by the high VIF.